# % Complete Roll up in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, task-list

I have a summary task and a couple of subtasks under the summary task. The %Complete on sub tasks are 10 and 20 % respectively. However, this is not rolling up tp the Summary task. The summary task still remains at 0%. Can anyone help me understand the issue here ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is SharePoint will not calculate the summary task percentage for you automatically.

You could develop an event receiver that updates the summary task every time a sub task is changed.

Or you could try developing a workflow that does the same thing.